# Read Next/Previous record via SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a simple client database (using MySQL). The app reads one record at a time. I want to be able to click a button to read next or read previous.

I don't have a recordset of found records. There is only ever one record found at a time.

The records have uniqueness guaranteed with a key of SURNAME+FIRSTNAME+CLIENTID.

To read the next record I do the below (which works fine). This assume I already have read a record so I know its current surname+givenname+clientid so getting the NEXT record is just a matter of selecting the one record that is "greater than" the current one (code shown below).

```
"select * from Clients where concat(Surname,GivenName,ClientID) > '" & SearchKey & "' ORDER BY Surname, GivenName, ClientID LIMIT 1"
```

If I have two records "David Morris" and "David Morrison" the NEXT record logic above works fine. But how do I go about reading the previous record?

***Example:*** Let's say I have the following 6 records in the database.

```
Morris, Alan
Morris, Barry
Morris, Charlie
Morris, David
Morrison, Andrew
Morrison, Brendon
```

I know I I want to work on a client record and I "THINK" his surname is Morrison (no idea of his first name). I want to bring up the first "Morrison" record and then press page down (or page up) until I find the one I want. Using my example 6 records, the first one I would find is Morrison-Andrew. I can press page down and I will find Morrison-Brendon. But that is not the client I wanted. So I press page up instead and now go backwards. From Morrison-Brendon, to Morrison-Andrew and then to Morris-David. Now I have the record I want. Morris-David.

If I had of used a select statement with ".....LIKE 'MORRISON%'...." then I would not have been able to page-up backwards to get to Morris-David.

Now I can always tell the client to use the app a different way, but this is the way that he wants it to work.

I have played around using ORDER BY with DESC sequence, but I have not found the right pattern to use yet.

Comment: In which language you are trying to access db ?

Comment: This where clause is not likely indexable: `where concat(Surname,GivenName,ClientID)`  If this query runs often, you may want to generate a computed column and index it (or use a function index if available).

Comment: Usually it would be as `where concat(Surname,GivenName,ClientID) < {value} ORDER BY Surname desc, GivenName desc, ClientID desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: This seems like a strange way to use a database.  Generally I would think you would want to just use select * from clients where [some condition] order by surname, givenname, client_id or something like that. Can you explain the larger context. Then maybe we can give you a better answer. Also why not use <.

Comment: Why don't you have unique id column?

Comment: Ravi. It VB.NET
Brandon. I think I may need to do as you suggest.
Abhik. I tried that, but the order-by of Surname does not take into consideration the other two parts of the index. I really need the order-by to be the entire concatinated field.
Dan B. I will edit the post to include an example to highlight why it  needs to work the way it does.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I did not realise you could use CONCAT() as part of the ORDER BY clause.

Next Button

```
select * from Clients where concat(Surname,GivenName,ClientID) > '" & SearchKey & "' ORDER BY concat(Surname, GivenName, ClientID) LIMIT 1
```

Previous Button

```
select * from Clients where concat(Surname,GivenName,ClientID) < '" & SearchKey & "' ORDER BY concat(Surname, GivenName, ClientID) DESC LIMIT 1
```